# What do the blue blocks in spark stage DAG visualisation UI mean?

Tags: apache-spark

in the following snip for the application UI, what do the blue blocks in each stage represent?

What do "Exchange" and "WholeStageCodeGen", etc mean?

Where can I find a resource to interpret what spark is doing here?

Many thanks

[image: What are the blue blocks? What do their names represent?]

Comment: Can you please provide the cause you're using to create this graph?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Each blue box is the steps of Apache Spark job.

You are asking about the `WholeStageCodegen` this stuff is:

> Whole-Stage Code Generation (aka WholeStageCodegen or WholeStageCodegenExec) fuses multiple operators (as a subtree of plans that support codegen) together into a single Java function that is aimed at improving execution performance. It collapses a query into a single optimized function that eliminates virtual function calls and leverages CPU registers for intermediate data.

You can see details here [SPARK-12795](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12795)

The exchange means the Shuffle Exchange between jobs in more details:

> ShuffleExchange is a unary physical operator. It corresponds to Repartition (with shuffle enabled) and RepartitionByExpression logical operators (as translated in BasicOperators strategy).

All this information you can get in your code using the `explain` [command](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.explain)

Each step shows you what your dataframe is going to do, this is good to find if your logic is right. If you want more details about Spark UI I suggest you to see [this](https://databricks.com/session/deep-dive-into-monitoring-spark-applications-using-web-ui-and-sparklisteners) presentation of Spark Summit and read [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-catalyst-QueryPlan.html) article about the execution planning.

These information will show you much more about your doubt.

Comment: explain command is very useful to check optimizations done by spark.

Comment: the spark summit presentation leads to the main page of the web site.

Comment: Ow! They have changed the link. Thanks @FlorianCastelain I will update

Comment: blue box is steps inside a stage.. not job. A job consists of number of stages.